# How can i track memory allocation?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, memory-leaks, mmap

I have a very unique problem, i am running Linux on a special hardware which is an Octeon based hardware. I see that my process keeps allocating memory upon performing a specific operation. I would like to track which part of the code is making this call.

Here is the details about my environment

1. Octeon MIPS architecture 32 bit.
2. Linux kernel 2.6
3. Minimal linux implementation.

However here are the my options/limitations that i need to work around.

1. Not sure if creating my own malloc will help. If this is possible can someone explain please?
2. Cannot use tools like walgrind, not available for this architecture.
3. Code base is huge, dont understand it fully, hence review isnt feasible and quick.
4. strace gives me the memory address that is allocated, but how can i figure out the code from that created this?

Please suggest if there is some way to go about this.

Thanks a lot.

Another thing i forgot to mention, the virtual memory of the process goes on increasing up-to 1.4GB at which, it stops and i see the allocs in the code fail with ENOMEM. Is this 1.4 GB limitation something to do with 32 bit machine? AFAIU 32 bit machine should allow 3 GB of virtual memory per process isnt it? Also, there is no per process limitation, i have confirmed this with setrlimit/getrlimit.

Cheers,
Pavan

Comment: Does the code compile for x86? Then you can use valgrind there and catch at least the non platform specific leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Torp, code does compile for x86, but this isnt reproducible on x86 platform. Only on Octeon, i can see strace pop up lots and lots of mmap2 calls indicating some memory allocation happening. When i run the same usecase on x86, i dont see the mmap2 calls at all.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write an wrapper function over `malloc`, You can do so without modifying each and every instance in your code where the function is called, a simple macro trick shall suffice:

```
void* my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func);

#define malloc(X) my_malloc( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)

void* my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func)
{

    void *p = malloc(size);
    printf ("Allocated = %s, %i, %s, %p[%li]\n", file, line, func, p, size);

    /*Link List functionality goes in here*/

    return p;
}
```

Similarly, You can also map `free` to call your own function.

You can maintain a list of allocated addresses and keep on adding new entries in `malloc` and removing relevant entries from the list in `free`. What remains in the list at the end of the program is leaking memory with locations.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, i will try this and revert back on my findings.

Comment: Hope printf does not make any malloc call, if not this will become a recursive hell :)

Comment: @PavanMysore: It doesn't and in your case you don't need `printf` anyways :)

Comment: Great! Thanks a billion, however stupid of me to not think of this approach. I still have a challenge though, i should ensure all thru the linkage this my_malloc should get used, i will need to check how i can make this macro globally visible, and mask the actual malloc.

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid, will this work even in library functions that my program links against. I doubt it will work in case of dynamic libraries that i link against. Any idea how i can solve those cases?

Comment: @PavanMysore: for your first comment, Yes thats a given the macro should be visible in all source files using `malloc` and `free`.Library code is already linked and just binaries so no it wont work for them.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to define the macro AFTER you make a call to the original `malloc` (in the line `void *p = malloc(size);`)

Comment: Any idea how i can tackle those cases :(

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/). Should be a lot less architecture dependent than valgrind.